# Watch task doesn't compile sass files

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs

So i am trying to set up my first grunt application, but i am struggling with the watch task.

When I run the task watch looks like it is working when i change my sass files, but the css files are not updated, so it looks like it is not compiling.

I am wondering if i need to install something else, for me this is all new... and i am not sure if I understand, because it looks very simple but I just cant make it work.

So here is my code

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
  watch:{
     sass:{
        options: {
            livereload: true
        },
        files:['sass/**/*.scss'],
        task:['sass']
    },
    css: {
        files: ['css/*.css'],
        tasks: []
    }
},
sass: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'sass',
            src: ['*.scss', '*.sass'],
            dest: 'css/',
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    }
  }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your `livereload` to be on the `css` files instead of `scss`.  As it is the compiled file that you want to be reloaded and not the preprocessed (`scss`) file.

**Example**

```
watch:{
     sass:{        
        files:['sass/**/*.scss'],
        task:['sass']
     },
     css: {
        options: {
            livereload: true
        },
        files: ['css/*.css']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OWWWWW....

I just found the problem... it should have been "tasks" not "task", i wasted sooo much time, on finding this little thingy!